# Problemas com ngFor de objeto contendo objetos

Tags: ionic, angular

Estou utilizando ele da seguinte maneira:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let via of lines.daysOperations?.week?.tripA?.routes; let i = index" text-wrap (click)="toggleGroup(i+'i')"
                      [ngClass]="{active: isGroupShown(i+'i')}">
```

E esta dando este error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Via Recanto Verde'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
>   Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Via Recanto Verde'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Meu objeto é assim:

```
{ outros itens ..., routes: {name: "lorem inpsum", schedules:{10:00, 11:00, 12:00}}}
```

Como posso resolver isto ??

Coloquei o operador `elvis ?` porém não solucionou meu problema.

Comment: O objeto está var lines = { daysOperations: { week: { tripA: {routes: { }}  }}} ?

Comment: sim neste fluxo

Comment: Seus "routes" são um array? Se sim, ele é o único array? O ngFor serve apenas para iterar em arrays

Comment: Não entendi sua indagação.

Comment: Dentro de routes tenho:

routes: {

name: "Lorem Inpsum"
Schedules:{
  11:00,
  12:00
}
}

Comment: @GabrielBerlanda meu routes é um objeto, e dentro dele tenho um array.

Comment: Você deve usar o ngFor em um array, em quem você quer iterar? em schedules? Se sim você deve alterar o fim do seu ngFor => *ngFor="let via of lines.daysOperations?.week?.tripA?.routes.schedules"

Comment: O ngFor espera um array pra ele iterar, não vai iterar em um objeto...

Comment: A minha outra dúvida era se todos os níveis que você acessa são objetos e só o último nível é um array, pois você tem alguns objetos com o nome no plural, ex: lines e daysOperations

Comment: @GabrielBerlanda Na verdade hoje este routes ele é um, porém a ideia é varias routes... Porém identifiquei um erro no modelo de dados. Verificarei mais a fundo, qualquer coisa atualizo a pergunta.. Obrigada por enquanto a todos

Comment: Sim, ao meu ver você tem alguns níveis ai, e você deve ir iterando um por um até chegar no último

Comment: `lines.daysOperations?.week?.tripA?.routes` está sendo acessado como um objeto, por isso retornou `'[object Object]'`, é preciso verificar se esse parâmetro `routes` é realmente um array para ser iterado pelo `ngFor`